# OL 4.2 WMS getGetFeatureInfoUrl producing incorrect URL

Tags: openlayers

EDIT: URL works fine, I mistakenly thought i,j, width, and height were sending info specific to the WMS image being checked for features.

I could be misunderstanding how the URL works so correct me if I'm wrong. The I, J, height and width attributes are all used to locate the feature on the image correct? When I provide getGetFeatureInfoUrl with different coordinates and viewResolutions, I always get the same location attributes in my URL.

When I create url using getGetFeatureInfoUrl, no matter what the coordinate or viewresolution, the i and j values are always 50. The height and width are also always 101.

Here are some examples:

```
"URL: http://localhost/geoserver/workspace/wfs?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=workspace%3Atable_points&LAYERS=workspace%3Atable_points&time=1500402731190&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=620954.1142031327%2C-34459035.34341003%2C8526377.327569202%2C-26553612.130043965"
Coordinate: -30506323.736727,4573665.720886167
ViewResolution: 78271.51696402048

"URL: http://localhost/geoserver/workspace/wfs?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=workspace%3Atable_points&LAYERS=workspace%3Atable_points&time=1500402501193&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=7044436.526761843%2C9118631.726308389%2C10997148.133444877%2C13071343.332991423"  
Coordinate: 11094987.529649906,9020792.33010336  
ViewResolution: 39135.75848201024  

"URL: http://localhost/geoserver/workspace/wfs?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=workspace%3Atable_points&LAYERS=workspace%3Atable_points&time=1500402511193&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=-2822992.6322137713%2C-1506726.7015574016%2C5082430.581152298%2C6398696.511808667"  
Coordinate: 2445984.905125633,1129718.974469263  
ViewResolution: 78271.51696402048

"URL: http://localhost/geoserver/workspace/wfs?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=workspace%3Atable_points&LAYERS=workspace%3Atable_points&time=1500402511193&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=-5405952.6920264475%2C-10429679.635455731%2C2499470.5213396214%2C-2524256.4220896624"  
Coordinate: -6476968.028772697,-1453241.085343413
ViewResolution: 78271.51696402048
```

Here's this HTML if it helps:

```
var displayFeatureInfo = function(coord, pixel)
{
    var features;
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
    var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    var url = pointLayer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        coord, viewResolution, 'EPSG:4326',
        {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'});
    if (url) {
      features = url;
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
    }
};

map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    displayFeatureInfo(evt.coordinate, evt.pixel);
});
```

Edit: 
I believe I found the issue. Here is the relevant openlayers code, line 141(https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/9fc0fb5e74146cd9a0c99926bed1a0f51fc745ad/src/ol/source/imagewms.js).

When creating the 'extent' openlayers always uses a default image size, which is [101,101].

Comment: You must show your code and where it takes the pixel coordinates of the point that user clicks on the map.

Comment: The example in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html seems to work as supposed.

Comment: It also produces URLs with i,j=50 and width,height=101. The only thing that changes is the BBOX. I guess that is where the click location is being sent. I misunderstood how the URL works.

Comment: Ok, feels like a trick but it gives a right result, doesn't it? Info is taken from the center of that sliding window.

Comment: Yea, it works correctly. I just didn't realize geoserver used the center of the bounding box to locate the features.

Comment: The original idea of GetFeatureInfo was to use the same BBOX, WIDTH, and HEIGHT which were used when the map was loaded with GetMap and change the values of i and j (earlier x and y) for locating the clicked pixel, but it is possible to use some creative tricks like in this case. GeoServer does not use the center of bounding box automatically but it interprets i=50 and j=50 as explicitly set by OpenLayers.

Comment: I and j are pixel coordinates of the image created by the original GetMap request, in WMS version 1.3.0.